# PHP, function replacing of extension class

Tags: php, function, class, extend

Imagine I have a class like this

```
class MyClass {
    private function func1() {
        // Much code
        func2();
        // Much code
    }
    private function func2() {
        echo 'old class';
    }
}
```

would it be possible to extend this class and replace the function func2() there, so that in new class, the func1() would use new func2(). Like this:

```
class MyNewClass extends MyClass {
    private function func2() {
        echo 'new class';
    }
}
```

But the method I described will still echo 'old class' for MyNewClass, but how it would be possible to replace the parent function?

Comment: Make it `protected` instead of `private`, then override in descending class.

Comment: Make protected in the new class, on in the extended class?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for property visibility in PHP classes : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: @user902100 in `MyClass` from your example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to still run func2 from the old class, but run more code in func2 in the new class. To do this, just call the parent in the new class function. Like so:

```
private function func2() {
    echo 'new class';
    parent::func2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented, use public or protected. The difference between the two modifiers can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

```
class MyClass {
    public function func1() {
        // Much code
        func2();
        // Much code
    }
    public function func2() {
        echo 'old class';
    }
}

class MyNewClass extends MyClass {
    private function func2() {
        echo 'new class';
    }
}
```